# Jquery removes a div from a table row element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js

I want to insert some table cells at a specific location into a table, so I mark this location with a , e.g.

```
<tr>
  <td>first</td>
  <div class='insert-here'></div>
  <td>last</td>
</tr>
```

However, jquery removes the div where it should be included, for example

```
$('<tr><div class="asd"></div></tr>') returns [<tr></tr>]
```

The simple solution is to tag the first cell and insert after this. Since I am using backbone views, the view will have the context of the entire row, instead of just its cells.

Has anyone come up with a nice solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this?

```
 $("tr td .insert-here").before("<div id='new_div'>helo</div>");
 $("tr td .insert-here").remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

`<tr>` elements may *only* contain `<td>` or `<th>` elements as children.

Comment: Is there a spec for these rules that JQuery uses to sanitise input, like a EBNF grammar or something.

Comment: @user1911731: jQuery isn't doing it, the browser is. You can find all the HTML spec at w3.org, for example: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/tr.html

Comment: PS: ["Zero or more of: one `td` element, or one `th` element"](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/tr.html#tr-content-model). So a `<tr>` can contain `<td>` *or* `<th>` children.

Comment: @user1911731 [Mozilla Developer Network HTML Elements Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element)